# How do I analyze this sentence from John Dyson's "Don't Look Down"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, participles

John Dyson's *DON'T LOOK DOWN* has a sentence that reads:

> The cable heaping on the roof, even a vibration from the men inside, could nudge the 2.4-ton cage into free fall.

**The cable heaping on the roof**  part appears to me a *misplaced modifier* as it's apparently modified by **a vibration**, which I don't think should be as such.

I tried comparing the sentence with—

> Dagger in hand, he darted across to assault the man.

Here it's clear that **Dagger (being) in hand** is a participle phrase modifying **he.**

What am I missing here?

Further, is it OK to use the second comma in the sentence ( appearing before *could nudge*) or had one best omit it?

Comment: You are correct in saying that this sentence is unclear. After a *second* reading, I would interpret (or rewrite it) thus: "The heaping of the cable on its roof, or even a vibration from the men inside, could nudge the 2.4-ton cage into a free fall."

Comment: No misplaced modifier, but a list of two items that could cause danger. **Wind, even rain, could cause danger**.  The piled cable, even a vibration, could nudge the heavy cage to fall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis of the Dagger sentence is on target, but the Cable sentence is quite different in structure. The two comma-separated phrases that begin the Cable sentence are  grammatical *subjects* for the predicate that follows, while the subject of the Dagger sentence is *he,* modified as you note by the preceding expression.

Having two subjects thus share a single predicate is a form of *[zeugma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_and_syllepsis).*  (It is of Type 3 per the typology in the linked Wikipedia page.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Brian Donovan!

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly an example of a compound subject with the coordinator **or** deleted for dramatic (staccato) effect:

> The cable heaping on the roof, [or] even a vibration from the men
> inside, could nudge the 2.4-ton cage into free fall.

A ... or even B ... could do X. ==> A, even B, could do X.

The comma after 'inside' forces the compound subject analysis.

Answer (score 2):

The mental image I have from this is of a cage (a mine shaft cage) being lowered and sticking in one position; the cable is still paid out from above and heaps on the cage top because the operator does not know the cage has stuck; in consequence, the situation of the occupants is dangerous because even their own small movement (the vibration) might free the cage, leading to its perilous and uncontrolled descent.

{Because of the circumstance of} the cable heaping {and perhaps continuing to heap} on the roof, even a vibration {any small movement} from the men inside could nudge the 2.4-ton cage into free fall.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, @Anton! Superb answer, I appreciate your help!